# Strange issue with an array

Tags: java, eclipse

So I'm in the middle of working on a class called planner [no main in it as it's a separate class], but I'm having an issue with declaring an array with eclipse. You will need to enter it in eclipse to see what it is because I have no idea what it means by 'Syntax error on token ";", , expected'.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Planner {
private int maxEvents = 1000;
private int numEvents = 0;
private int choice;
int[] anArray;
anArray = new int [1000];

public void Planner() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Press 1 to add an event. 2 to display events for the day. 3 to display events for the week. 4 to quit:    ");
    choice = scan.nextInt();
    if (choice == 1){addEvent();}
    if (choice == 2){displayOneDate();}
    if (choice == 3){displayOneWeek();}
    if (choice == 4){System.out.println("Have a good day.");}
    else {Planner();}   
}

public void addEvent() {
    Event newEvent = new Event();
    if (numEvents == maxEvents){System.out.println("Error: No more room.");}
    else {
        for (int i=0; anArray.length > i; i++) {
            numEvents++;
            newEvent.getEventFromUser();
        }
    }
}

public void displayOneDate() {
    System.out.println("Event one: " + anArray[0]);
}

public void displayOneWeek() {

}
}
```

Comment: Why do u put the if / else statements on one line? It makes your code hard to read

Comment: else {Planner();} , what does this do?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare

```
int[] anArray;
anArray = new int [1000];
```

it should be

```
int[] anArray = new int [1000];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have executable code in class directly. You should have it either in method or constructor.
Otherwise if you want initialize the array you have to write like this  int[] anArray = new int [1000];